# SOLR Index a remote file

Tags: curl, indexing, solr

Does anyone know how to index a remote file using SOLR? I've tried the following

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=rem1&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=body&commit=true" -F stream.url=http://fakesite.com
```

with no luck.

The local host equivalent

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=rem1&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=body&commit=true" -F "stream.url=http://duke.edu/web/aepi/"
```

works fine.

Thanks!
djs22

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons, remote streaming is disabled by default. From the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Streaming_Consideration):

> If streaming is enabled, you need to
>   make sure Solr is as secure as it
>   needs to be. When streaming is
>   enabled, the parameters "stream.url"
>   will go to a remote site and download
>   the content. Likewise, "stream.file"
>   will read a file on disk.
>
> Streaming is disabled by default and
>   is configured from solrconfig.xml
>
> ```
>  <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" ... />
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, I already had that enabled though. Must be something wrong with my curl syntax, probably a naive mistake.